# Google App Script MailApp.sendEmail() quota or time limit for emails?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm working on code that, based on the results of a Google Form submit, could email anywhere from 1 to 15 different email addresses the results of the Form submit.

The problem that I'm running into is this - only the first email in my queue of emails is being sent. I have no idea what happens to the rest of them - if they're failing they're failing completely silently, but they certainly aren't showing up in the inboxes of the people they're supposed to.

Here's some relevant code: this is the loop that sends a personalized email to each person in an array of email address strings

```
// sendArray is an array of email strings
// receiptArray is an array of recipient email address strings
while(sendArray.length != 0) {
    MailApp.sendEmail(receiptArray.pop(), "Subject line", sendArray.pop());
}
```

As the title would suggest I think there's some quota or defined time limit between email sends that I'm not aware of, but I can't find any trace of it in Google's documentation. Any ideas how I can get more than just the first email to send?

**Clarification**

I haven't tried another type of loop, but I'm looking at my quotas with getRemainingDailyQuota and it's only 'charging' me for the one email I'm sending.

Comment: Your clarification didn't answer my main question : What is the content of sendQueue ?

Comment: Whoops. That's actually a typo, sorry. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Quotas are [shown here](https://docs.google.com/macros/dashboard), I'm not sure you are hitting a limit, I have a script that sends a lot of mails in one single run (more than 800) without issue.

Have you tried another type of loop ? What is the content of `sendQueue` ? is it modified somewhere else in your script ?

Comment: I'll add that info to the question

Comment: You could try to add `Logger.log(sendArray.length)` in the loop to see its actual length and if it changes.